# Does an Array's specified capacity include 0?

Tags: java, arrays

When you declare an array:

```
int[] array = new int[2]
```

When you specify the capacity of it (in this case 2) does this include 0 or not? If it did include 0 the indexes would be: 0,1,2 and if it didn't it would be 1,2
Please answer this question as I really need to know.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you read the manual?

Comment: The indexes "availables" would be 0 and 1 for an array of size 2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unwillingness for reading the _fantastic_ manual.

Comment: This is just a case of RTM.

Comment: This question could be of any worth if you asked int[2] means indexes 0,1 or 0,1,2. but now this qn doesnt make any sense. I didn't downvote though

Comment: Gods people are so harsh on this website! I can't believe 6 people down voted this and I have seen some obvious questions which have received like 300+ votes up. I DO read the manual (my Java book) but it didn't say anything about this... I think I'll stick with Yahoo as people seem to be a lot nicer on there. Thank you to the people who DIDN'T downvote this and now my reputation has gone from 10 to 1. Stack overflow SUCKS :( I'm just a noob for god sake, no need to be mean...

Comment: @prash I did actually mean that in some respects I just was a bit confused. Thank you for not down-voting my question though :) To everyone who thought this was a stupid question, please keep in mind that I am probably a lot younger than you guys as I am only 15...

Comment: @TheGeek Age doesn't matter here. what one speaks only matters.

Comment: @devnull and everyone here I am announcing that I will be going back with Yahoo answers cos it's way better!! I am sick of loosing reputation and then gaining some and then loosing some again! Everyone is so mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call capacity, is the size, or even better the length of the array, i.e. the amount of items that you can store in the array.

The indexing always start from ZERO, therefore, as you can also easily figure out yourself, if you start from ZERO and you have an array of length N, the indexes start from zero and ends in N-1, i.e. the last item in the array is at the N-1 index.

Comment: Best answer I have seen on SO in a while. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes are `0, 1`. What you are specifying is the size of the array, and there are indeed 2 elements, but they are numbered starting from `0`.